# Average a list of Drawing.Point

Tags: c#, list, point

I have a `List<System.Drawing.Point>` and need to calculate the average of the points:

how can I do this with LINQ?

I tried this:

`MyList.Average();` and I get this:
Error   1   Instance argument: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable'

Comment: I'm guessing its because `Point` would need a selector run over it first. Have you tried a `Select` to collapse the list into something averageable first?

Comment: What is the `Point` class and what do you consider being the average?

Comment: Start out doing this using a pen and paper, then one at a time, map the steps that you're following into code.

Comment: I dont think there is an overload that takes only IEnumerable<TSource>

Comment: @Selman22 Yes, that's exactly what the error message is telling him.

Comment: Is `Point` just a class with X and Y coordinates?

Comment: Is it `System.Drwaing.Point`? If so, what's the average of multiple points? They have two values: `X` and `Y`. Do you want the combination of the average of `X` and `Y`? So like this: `Point avgPoint=new Point(); avgPoint.X=(int)points.Average(p => p.X);avgPoint.Y=(int)points.Average(p => p.Y);`

Comment: George, I added the Point class details

Comment: @Matias and how do you calculate the average of that? Do you average x and y separately and those become the new x and y? Do you do something else?

Comment: Hi George, just average of X and Y and that is a new point I will use

Comment: Then DavidG's answer below works great though keep in mind that points are `int` and the average can easily end up being a decimal so you need a strategy to resolve

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need to average out the X and Y components individually, then this will do the job:

```
var avgPoint = new System.Drawing.Point 
{
    X = (int)Math.Round(MyList.Average(p => p.X)),
    Y = (int)Math.Round(MyList.Average(p => p.Y))
};
```

Comment: I would do something like `(int)Math.Round(MyList.Average(p => p.X))`

Comment: @GeorgeMauer That's probably better, I've added in `Math.Round` at least.

Comment: Also note in my comment - `Average` actually takes an expression so no need to `Select` first

Comment: @GeorgeMauer Yeah, much simpler.